# HTML code for images from a different folder. Sublime

Tags: html, image

I am trying to display an image using the following code, but the image is not appearing. Any idea what I need to do?

```
<img src="./images/macbook.jpeg" alt="MacBook">
```

Comment: We can't help troubleshoot a faulty path or missing file. You'll have to do that using your browser's console, network tab, etc.

Comment: Where is the image relative to the document file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<img src="../images/macbook.jpeg" alt="MacBook">` 
`./` is the the folder that the working file is in.
You have to use `../` to go up

Comment: This would look for the image up one directory level from the document. What makes you think that's what's needed?

Comment: Just a try because he postet not enough information about the directory structure and error type

Comment: @BrandonLee nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.
|-- index.html
|-- images
    |-- macbook.jpeg
```

That needs to be the folder structure, for `./images/macbook.jpeg` to work.